# QiskitError Cannot convert condition in circuit with multiple classical registers to instruction

Tags: qiskit, error-correction

I got a qiskit error *'Cannot convert condition in circuit with multiple classical registers to instruction'* when I used multiple individual classical registers, such as `cr0`, `cr1` and `cr2`, in a code of a simple error correction. I've written a reproduction code as follows.

Though, the code works fine if I use only 1 classical register in a manner of array, such as `cr = ClassicalRegister(3)`.

I wonder the error in this case is expected.

FYI: `qiskit_version: {'qiskit-terra': '0.25.1', 'qiskit': '0.44.1', 'qiskit-aer': '0.12.2', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.7.1', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.20.2'}`

Here's a reproduction code :

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister,transpile
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider
import qiskit.tools.jupyter


qr = QuantumRegister(5, "q")
cr0 = ClassicalRegister(1)
cr1 = ClassicalRegister(1)
cr2 = ClassicalRegister(1)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr0, cr1, cr2)

qc.initialize(0,0)
qc.initialize(0,1)
qc.initialize(0,2)

qc.h(0)

qc.cx(0,1)
qc.cx(0,2)
qc.barrier()

qc.x(0)

qc.cx(0,3)
qc.cx(1,3)
qc.cx(0,4)
qc.cx(2,4)

qc.measure(3, cr1)
qc.measure(4, cr1)
qc.barrier()

with qc.if_test((cr0, 1)) as else_:
    with qc.if_test((cr1, 1)) as else_1:
        qc.x(0) #|11>
    with else_1: 
        qc.x(1) #|10>
with else_:
    with qc.if_test((cr1,1)):
        qc.x(2) #|01>

qc.barrier()

qc.measure(0,cr0)
qc.measure(1,cr1)
qc.measure(2,cr2)

qc.draw("mpl")
provider = IBMProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
job = AerSimulator().run(qc)
plot_histogram(job.result().get_counts())
```

[image]